# Check if program is installed in C

Tags: c

I'd like to find a way to find out if a program is installed using C gnu11 standard, for example, will the command 'Rscript' work if it is executed using the `system` function in C.

I'm not a programmer by training, so I'm not sure if I'm using the correct search terms.

I would like the C equivalent of

```
con@con-Inspiron-3521:~/Scripts$ which Rscript 
/usr/bin/Rscript
```

how can I do that in C?

Comment: Well you could always use [`popen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to run `which Rscript` and capture the output.

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you want to find out what compiled the program? Or if the program is installed? Or are you just trying to run a bash command in C?

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar I want to see if I can execute "Rscript" within a C program.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there's no portable C way to do this. You may want to look at whether there's a POSIX equivalent, since that would still be decently portable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a similar effort you can just parse the `PATH` variable and check if the given file exists and is executable:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool can_run_command(const char *cmd) {
    if(strchr(cmd, '/')) {
        // if cmd includes a slash, no path search must be performed,
        // go straight to checking if it's executable
        return access(cmd, X_OK)==0;
    }
    const char *path = getenv("PATH");
    if(!path) return false; // something is horribly wrong...
    // we are sure we won't need a buffer any longer
    char *buf = malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(cmd)+3);
    if(!buf) return false; // actually useless, see comment
    // loop as long as we have stuff to examine in path
    for(; *path; ++path) {
        // start from the beginning of the buffer
        char *p = buf;
        // copy in buf the current path element
        for(; *path && *path!=':'; ++path,++p) {
            *p = *path;
        }
        // empty path entries are treated like "."
        if(p==buf) *p++='.';
        // slash and command name
        if(p[-1]!='/') *p++='/';
        strcpy(p, cmd);
        // check if we can execute it
        if(access(buf, X_OK)==0) {
            free(buf);
            return true;
        }
        // quit at last cycle
        if(!*path) break;
    }
    // not found
    free(buf);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @iharob: `strchr` is for the weak who loop over strings twice - once in `strchr`, once in `strcpy`. ;-) Just joking, it just felt more natural to write like this.

Comment: Yes, not checking `malloc()`'s return value is also very bad.

Comment: @iharob: `malloc` cannot fail on Linux systems (unless you ask for more than physical RAM + paging file), and in general I have yet to see any reasonably sized application deal "correctly" (whatever that means) with an out of memory. If `malloc` returns NULL for small allocations like this there's nothing you can reasonably do to save yourself, just crash. But still, if you prefer, I'll just add a useless check for that.

Comment: Is a program that got copied into another path (not in PATH) then considered "not installed"? (Just playing the devil's advocate here - for non-console users it may very well look that way, in practice....)

Comment: That doesn't mean that you can simply assume! Use android studio and see how it's very possible that your program misteriously crashed because the system ran out of memory. It's not useless at all, it's useful to abort the program stating there is no more memory instead of letting the user go crazy trying to understand "**Why did it crash!, it's a bug. Stupid developer!**". Also, having the good habit is simply good, your program could simply be such that it can ignore for the time being and retry later when it needs.

Comment: @RadLexus: here I'm referring to the "precise" version of the question i.e. "will the command 'Rscript' work if it is executed using the system function in C.". Of course it may be installed elsewhere, but then there's really no way to know unless you have either specific details about the program/the package manager/a full dump of the directory tree. :-P

Comment: @RadLexus It will then not be possible to execute such program without the full path. In fact, the term *installed* is more of a general term. It might also involve other things like data files and databases.

Comment: Note that your PATH parsing does not handle `.` as the directory at the start, in the middle, and at the end of this PATH value: `PATH=:/usr/bin:/bin::/usr/sbin:/sbin:`. An empty field counts as `.`, the current directory. Your code seems to treat it as if that were `/`, the root directory  (see [Environment Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03)). Also, if the name on the command line contains a slash, then it doesn't undergo PATH expansion — so if `cmd` in the function contains a slash, there's no analysis with PATH. This may not matter.

Comment: thanks @MatteoItalia that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thank you, it should be POSIXly correct now.

Comment: @con: there was an error in the final loop, now it should be correct

Answer (score 1):

The *which* program probably does a search for the file in any of the directories specified in the `PATH` environment variable.

There are many ways to do this, this is one such ways

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *head;
    const char *command;
    size_t length;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "insufficient number of arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }

    command = argv[1];
    length = strlen(command);
    // Get the PATH environment variable
    head = getenv("PATH");
    if (head == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "the PATH variable was not set, what?\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Find the first separator
    while (*head != '\0') {
        struct stat st;
        ptrdiff_t dirlen;        
        const char *tail;
        char *path;
        // Check for the next ':' if it's not found
        // then get a pointer to the null terminator
        tail = strchr(head, ':');
        if (tail == NULL)
            tail = strchr(head, '\0');
        // Get the length of the string between the head
        // and the ':'
        dirlen = tail - head;
        // Allocate space for the new string
        path = malloc(length + dirlen + 2);
        if (path == NULL)
            return -1;
        // Copy the directory path into the newly
        // allocated space
        memcpy(path, head, dirlen);
        // Append the directory separator
        path[dirlen] = '/';
        // Copy the name of the command            
        memcpy(path + dirlen + 1, command, length);
        // `null' terminate please
        path[dirlen + length + 1] = '\0';
        // Check if the file exists and whether it's
        // executable
        if ((stat(path, &st) != -1) && (S_ISREG(st.st_mode) != 0)) {
            if ((st.st_mode & (S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH)) == 0) {                
                fprintf(stdout, "found `%s' but it's not executable\n", path);
            } else {
                fprintf(stdout, "found at: %s\n", path);
            }                
        }
        // Don't forget to free!
        free(path);
        // Point to the next directory
        head = tail + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in general the same algorithm

1. Get the `PATH` environment variable, which consists of a sequence of directory paths separated by a `:` character.
2. Obtain each directory path in this sequence by iterating over it, this is where you can do it many ways.
3. Check if,

   - The file exists.
   - Has execution permissions for the caller.

Comment: Doesn't `S_IXUSR` just signify that the *owner of the file* can execute it?

Comment: @Rhymoid Yes it does, it would be better to use `S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH`